# How can I get nth row of div after mouse over this

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').on('mouseover', function() {
        alert($('div:eq(' + this + ')'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>aaaaa</div>
<div>aaaaa</div>
<div>aaaaa</div>
```

I want to get div nth-child of row after mouse move to over this div

e.g

```
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>aaaa</div>
```

If mouse over div nth-child(2) -> alert 2, over(3) -> alert 3

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over every element you get and add hover event on it

```js
$('div').each(function(index,elem){
    $(elem).hover(function(){
        alert(index+1);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>aaaa</div>
```

Comment: how can I stop repeat alert

Comment: You mean it alert twice?

Comment: yeah, I want stop alert twice :)

Comment: Hover triggers mouseenter and mouseleave event, so you might want to change it to mouseenter

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").mouseover(function(){
        alert("1");
    });
    $("#2").mouseover(function(){
        alert("2");
    });
    $("#3").mouseover(function(){
        alert("3");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">aaaa</div>
<div id="2">aaaa</div>
<div id="3">aaaa</div>

</body>
</html>
```

may this you want

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this,**

```
 $("div:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
```

});